# How to play a planeswalker such as Sorin, Lord of Innistrad?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When playing [Sorin, Lord of Innistrad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=368535), I know I add 1 loyalty counter at my upkeep. However if I have 6 loyalty my questions are:

1. Can I play the -2 ability twice or only once per upkeep?
2. My other question is can I play +1 and then -2 on the same upkeep?

Comment: You may wish to read [this](https://www.wizards.com/magic/tcg/article.aspx?x=magic/rules/planeswalkers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I know I add 1 loyalty counter at my upkeep.

huh? no. Outside of the effect of a spell or ability, you only add loyalty counters onto Sorin when you place it on the battlefield, and when you activate its +1 Loyalty ability.

> Can I play the -2 ability twice or only once per upkeep?

No, for two reasons.

1. You can't play it during your upkeep at all. Loyalty abilities can only be used "as a sorcery". (On your turn, in a main phase, when the stack is empty.)
2. You can only activate an ability of a given Planeswalker once per turn.

> My other question is can I play +1 and then -2 on the same upkeep?

No, for the same reasons.

---

> 606.3. A player may activate a loyalty ability of a permanent he or she controls any time he or she has priority and the stack is empty during a main phase of his or her turn, but only if no player has previously activated a loyalty ability of that permanent that turn.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer shortly. Have a 10 min counter. That makes sense and clears up my confusion.

Comment: Added the rule.